# Get-WmiObject without PowerShell

Tags: python, windows, wmi, wmic

I am writing a Windows python program that needs to query WMI. I am planning to do this by using the subprocess module to call `WMIC` with the arguments I need.

I see a lot of examples online of using WMI via PowerShell, usually using the "commandlet" `Get-WmiObject` or the equivalent `gwmi`.

How do you do the equivalent of `Get-WmiObject` without using PowerShell, but rather with `WMIC`?

Specificially, from within CMD.EXE, I want to do `powershell gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice`, but without using powershell; rather, I want to invoke `WMIC` directly.

Thanks, and sorry for the beginner question!

Comment: I found this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wmi/archive/2010/01/06/wmic-vs-wmi-powershell-cmdlets.aspx
But I am still not seeing any way to get the Win32_USBControllerDevice list from WMIC

Comment: Also found this: http://superuser.com/questions/331220/wmic-path-what-wmic-class-what

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason why you'd want to mess around with `wmic` instead of simply using python's [WMI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/) module?

Answer (score 0):

From CMD.EXE, I think the command I need is `wmic path Win32_USBControllerDevice get *`

So most likely the general pattern is:

- PowerShell: `gwmi MYCLASSNAME`
- translates into:
- CMD.EXE: `wmic path
  MYCLASSNAME get *`